# Can you say "The NOₓ are"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diesel_exhaust_fluid) says

> [...] Within the SCR catalyst, the NO<sub>*x*</sub> **are** catalytically reduced by the ammonia [...]

NO<sub>2</sub> is nitrogen dioxide, which is singular. *x* can take any one of a range of values, so NO<sub>*x*</sub> means

> nitrous oxide *or* nitrogen dioxide *or* dinitrogen pentoxide *or* other alternatives

and so is, logically, singular. If we regard NO<sub>*x*</sub> as **a** chemical of variable composition then this makes sense. *x* cannot logically have different values at once, but I think NO<sub>*x*</sub> is being used in this sentence to mean

> nitrous oxide *and* nitrogen dioxide *and* dinitrogen pentoxide *and* other alternatives, all mixed together

It is possible the grammar is also influenced by NO<sub>*x*</sub> sounding plural as it is pronounced "knocks".

So can we say "The NO<sub>*x*</sub> are" or not?

Comment: If anyone knows how to change the title to say NO\<sub>*x*\</sub>  (without the backslashes!),please can they do so?

Comment: So, if it were H2O molecules would you want to say "the waters is" or "the waters are"?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I don't think you can do that in titles on this site.

Comment: Is this like saying "the gases are" ?

Comment: @HotLicks It's not a question of how many molecules, but of how many *different* molecules. You might say the waters if you were talking about different types of water, e.g. Perrier and Highland Spring.

Comment: @AzorAhai That is the big question. You can say "the gases are" or "the various oxides of nitrogen are", but where is the boundary between  a mixture and a chemical of variable compositions (as many chemicals are). *Logically*,  NO*x* implies a chemical of variable composition, as opposed to a mixture. You say "gasoline is" even though it is a mixture of related chemicals, so perhaps you should say NO*x* is, even though it is a mixture of related chemicals.

Comment: @DavidRobinson So you would call a balloon filled with those chemicals a "NOx-filled balloon"?

Comment: @AzorAhai Yes, but that doesn't help as I would always use the singular in that context. If the balloon were full of cats I would call it a cat-filled balloon!

But I think you may have given me the answer. What we need is the plural of NO*ₓ*, i.e. NO*ₓ*s, which would be pronounced "Knoxes"?

Comment: @AzorAhai Thank you for helping with the title. I have just realized how to solve the problem as there is a character, ₓ for x subscript. Not ideal as NO*ₓ* will not be found if you search for NOx, but it works.

Comment: My point is that it's a lot clearer and less grammatically confusing to say "the NOx molecules are ...".

Comment: Perhaps the issue here is the idea of countability.  While the number of NOx molecules would typically be taken as uncountable and thus be treated singularly (as a phase), the categories of NOx's we'd be interested in are far more likely to be taken as countable, so plural.  That said, this can sometimes be a fuzzy qualification, e.g. in the debate over whether "_data_" is plural or not.

Comment: Here's an argument by analogy for "is": NOx is a gas containing different types of molecules, and so is air. Nobody would think of writing "The air are reduced ..." so why write "The NOx are reduced …"?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, but only if you are referring to Nitrogen Dioxide as a category. If you are referring specifically to the gas, the answer is no.

For example, "All types of NOx are converted in the reaction" - valid because it is referring to the *types* of NOx you have, which is multiple.

"All of my NOx is converted in the reaction" is referring to NOx as a mass noun, so there is no plural in that sense.

Comment: In both your examples, you have taken NOx out of the picture as far as verb agreement goes. All types are, All is. In other words, your examples don't have anything to do with the question or your explanations.

Comment: @PhilSweet for the second case, that's not true. There's still verb agreement with the main noun in this construction: "all of my sugar is sweet" vs "all of my sugar cubes are sweet".

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I figure you can. ***It just means the different nitrogen oxides***. I was surprised to read that it also includes Nitrous oxide, considering the 2 Nitrogen atoms, but in any case 'oxides' would take a plural form.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOx) says the following:

> In atmospheric chemistry, NOx is a generic term for the nitrogen
>   oxides that are most relevant for air pollution, namely nitric oxide
>   (NO) and nitrogen dioxide (NO2).[1][2] These gases contribute to the
>   formation of smog and acid rain, as well as affecting tropospheric
>   ozone.
>
> NOx gases are usually produced from the reaction among nitrogen and
>   oxygen during combustion of fuels, such as hydrocarbons, in air;
>   especially at high temperatures, such as occur in car
>   engines.[1][2][3] In areas of high motor vehicle traffic, such as in
>   large cities, the nitrogen oxides emitted can be a significant source
>   of air pollution. NOx gases are also produced naturally by lightning.
>
> The term NOx is chemistry shorthand for molecules containing one
>   nitrogen and one or more oxygen atom. It is generally meant to include
>   nitrous oxide (N2O),[1] although nitrous oxide is a fairly inert oxide
>   of nitrogen that has many uses as an oxidizer for rockets and car
>   engines, an anesthetic, and a propellant for aerosol sprays and
>   whipped cream. Nitrous oxide plays hardly any role in air pollution,
>   although it may have a significant impact on the ozone layer,[4] and
>   is a significant greenhouse gas.

In the same article NOx is used both in plural and in singular forms depending on whether it refers to various nitrogen oxides or to singular nitrogen oxide, e.g.

> Ott noted that the lightning-produced NOx is typically found at
>   altitudes greater than 5 km, while combustion and biogenic (soil) NOx
>   are typically found near the sources at near surface elevation (where
>   it can cause the most significant health effects).

Comment: As for the two N atoms, these  are stoichiometic formulae - just concerned with the ratios, not the amounts. So N2O counts as the same as NO½. N2O5 is also included as this counts as NO2½. The other problem, which does have linguistic significance is that N2O  does not count as a "nasty substance". Whereas the others are nasty pollutants, and indeed the acceptance of the term NOx may have been influenced by the word *noxious* which is apposite, N2O is not *noxious*. It is laughing gas which is quite pleasant to breathe and is used in aerosol whipped cream, so is often disregarded as a NOx.

Comment: The two plural references I can see are for "NOx gases are", where NOx is used as an adjective.   The singular references are when talking about the term "NOx" rather than what it represents ("Nox is a generic term" and "The term NOx is chemistry shorthand").  So "NOx" itself, as a shorthand for "nitrogen oxides" is not used as the subject of a verb at all, so we can't make any judgment based on that passage.

Comment: @Phil M Jones. This is the kind of sentence I was referring to in the article: NOx are typically found near the sources at near surface elevation (where it can cause the most significant health effects). NOx here refers to oxides and is not being used adjectivally. In any case I'll add it to the post.

Comment: @SConroy Hmm, that certainly brings it into the same category as sheep and fish.  Nice find.

Answer (score 2):

NOx is an abbreviation for what is referred to as "nitrogen oxides" in environmental regulations (e.g., 40 CFR 51.165(a)(1)(v)(E), 42 USC 7403(c)(3)(A)), so you can see why the Wikipedia entry chose this formulation. However, it's awkward. In actual usage in the environmental profession, people just use NOx like a mass noun (no article, singular agreement).

Answer (score 0):

***tl;dr*-**  Yes, "*the NO<sub>x</sub> are*" is a correct construction when referring to various nitrogen oxides, as the quoted excerpt from Wikipedia is.

---

Earlier in that same paragraph, [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diesel_exhaust_fluid):

> The excess of air necessarily leads to generation of [nitrogen oxides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOx) (NO<sub>*x*</sub>), which are harmful [pollutants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollutant), from the nitrogen in the air.

This makes it pretty clear that they're using "*NO<sub>x</sub>*" as shorthand for "*nitrogen oxides*".

Substituting that into the sentence you're asking about, it's:

> Within the SCR [catalyst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalyst), the [nitrogen oxides] are catalytically reduced by [...]

This all looks good to me.

Separately, the singular can also be correct in other contexts.  For example, when "*NO<sub>x</sub>*" is being used to refer to a specific nitrogen oxide in a general way, then the singular can be correct.  Of course, in the excerpt from Wikipedia, they're pointing out the catalytic conversion of various nitrogen oxides rather than just one sort of nitrogen oxide, so the plural's correct there.